# How to conditionally format alternative values?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table of repeated values and I want to add some conditional formatting so repeated values are dehighligthed and value changes are highlighted through alternative values, such as this:

[image: Table with repeated values, where odd distinct values are white and even distinct values are odd]

How can I manage this without VBA?

Answer (score 0):

I managed this through a combination of 2 conditional formats:

First, a conditional value for alternating background colors, which applies to cells where this formula is true (note that there is a circular reference at the end of the second line that makes it not work inside a cell, but it works without issues in the conditional format formula):

```
=LET(allaboveandme;OFFSET(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(1;COLUMN()));0;0;ROW();1);
indexeswithme;MATCH(allaboveandme;allaboveandme;0);
distinctwithme;SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(indexeswithme;indexeswithme)>0;1));
ISODD(distinctwithme))
```

This will paint alternating distinct values the way you instruct.

I also added another conditional formatting to add an upper border where values change, like so:

```
=NOT(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()-1;COLUMN()))=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW();COLUMN())))
```

Comment: A much simpler solution is possible. For highlight you can use formula ```=A2<>A1``` and for dehighlight - ```=A2=A1```. Apply to range ```A2:A100...```

Comment: That's basically what I did with the second formula - but in the conditional format you need to reference the cell indirectly, so instead of A2 you need to say indirect(address(row();column())). Or did I misunderstand you?

Comment: No, you don't have to use ```INDIRECT``` if you don't want to. And taking into account that it is a volatile function, it would be better not to want it. If you use simple ```=A1<>A2``` formula, it works for all Apply to range changing relative references accordingly for each cell in range.

Comment: Thanks! I did not know that! If you add it as an answer I'll accept it as the good one.